# How to make MultiValueField with Composite Fields and i18n enabled work properly?

Tags: magnolia

Have anyone tried to have a form with MultiValueField in Magnolia having Composite fields with i18n enabled and is working properly?

Currently, I'm encountering some weird behaviour when adding items to English then switching to other language and adding items again then switch back to English with items all gone. In one JIRA post it said it was already fixed but I still encounter this issue. Also encountered issues in sorting which apparently not supported by the DelegatingMultiValueTransformer.

If so, can you please show me the configuration you use to make this work properly? If needed customisation, can you give me ideas on how to do it?

Would really appreciate any help on this.

Btw, I'm using the latest release 5.4.6 now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you don't want to put two questions in one request in the future ;)

Re language issue:
did you check that you have i18n enabled also on the subfields, since you are using deletage transformer? AFAIK with delegate you need to have them enabled on all fields in the hierarchy.

Re transformer & ordering:
IMO the only way out is to write custom transformer. Look at source code of `MultiValueTransformer` and in the part of the code where it goes just two levels down when checking child values, you need to go deeper.
You would also need to define different structure storage for your values there since one used by the `MultiValueTransformer` would not suffice for multiple levels.
Perhaps you can extend one of the more specialized `MultiValue*Transformer` or perhaps you try `MultiValueJSONTransformer` if storing all values in json array is enough for you (you would still need to extend it and to repopulate values back into dialog when opening dialog for editing).

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Ok, I will look further into this transformer.  The https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MGNLUI-3633 seems not yet fixed, so I need to explore this area as well. Thanks!